# MP4Client not working

Tags: segmentation-fault

I just installed GPAC using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gpac
```

When I try to use MP4Client:

```
MP4Client video.mp4
```

I get:

```
Using config file in /home/user/.gpac directory
System info: 15990 MB RAM - 8 cores
Modules Found : 38 
Loading GPAC Terminal
[Thread MediaManager] Couldn't set priority(2) for thread ID 0x17e7e700
[Thread MediaManager] Couldn't set priority(2) for thread ID 0x17e7e700
Terminal Loaded in 87 ms
Hit 'h' for help

[iso file] Unknown box type st3d
[iso file] Unknown box type sv3d
[iso file] Unknown box type svhd
[iso file] Unknown box type proj
[iso file] Unknown box type prhd
[iso file] Unknown box type equi
[iso file] Unknown box type gsst
[iso file] Box "data" is invalid in container gsst
[iso file] Unknown box type gstd
[iso file] Box "data" is invalid in container gstd
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any idea about what is going on?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to view a 360 video file that, is either not supported by MP4Client, or it is badly packaged.

You can try again after installing the latest version from the official repo https://github.com/gpac/gpac

Also, you can get more info on the file by using an other gpac tool called MP4Box (i.e. MP4Box -info )